aws certificate manager failing validation for multilevel domains
I have a hosted zone in Route 53 that I'm trying to create certs for with AWS Certificate Manager. The validation process fails whether I do DNS or email validation for any subdomains other than the APEX or a wildcard subdomain like example.com and *.example.com.
The domains that fail to create a certificate are:
dev.example.com
api.dev.example.com
api.example.com

I'm doing this through the web console. I assume any additional domains added after the first one are Subject Alternative Names. Am I missing a crucial understanding of how certs work?
This page from AWS docs shows examples of multilevel subdomains:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html
All failed cert issuings are noted as CAA errors. I do not have a CAA record for this domain but I've also tried creating a valid CAA record to see if that works and it doesn't.
It seems like I can only get a cert created for example.com and *.example.com.
